# gentoo xfce auth problem

Tags: login, xfce, d-bus, consolekit

When i launch xfce on normla user: with consolekit and dbus i have all shutdown,reboo,suspend etc buttons but the are grey inactive. Without consolekit and dbus I can shutdown but ther are no susupend and hibernation buttons. To launch xfce by script in .bashrc How to enable shutdown and suspen options for normal user?